# how to play music stop and start until end of it?

Tags: python

I can play it until the end of test.flv ,but i have a special requirement.

```
import os
os.system("D:\\VLC\\vlc.exe  g:\\test.flv")
```

I want to play the test.flv for 3 minutes and stop for 2 minutes and go on to play (from the last stop point not from beginning) for 3 minutes so on and on untill the end of test.flv.

Comment: You need to use some library which can handle audio. Take a look at pygame for instance.

Comment: Were you able to get something out of my answer?

Comment: i can't install pygame in py3.3 ,can't test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to use specificaly VLC- it has http interface, so you could use that to control player

Just launch your player

```
x:\path\vlc\vlc.exe -I http g:\test.flv
```

This command will Create web server with 8080 (by default) listening port

`127.0.0.1:8080/requests/status.xml` contans all information about currently playing file

This will play / pause current track

`127.0.0.1:8080/requests/status.xml?command=pl_pause`

Here is A list of available http commands

## status.xml: Get VLC status information, current item info and meta.

add  to playlist and start playback: `?command=in_play&input=<mrl>`

add  to playlist: `?command=in_enqueue&input=<mrl>`

play playlist item : `?command=pl_play&id=<id>`

toggle pause. If current state was 'stop', play item : `?command=pl_pause&id=<id>`

stop playback: `?command=pl_stop`

jump to next item: `?command=pl_next`

jump to previous item: `?command=pl_previous`

delete item  from playlist: `?command=pl_delete&id=<id>`

empty playlist: `?command=pl_empty`

sort playlist using sort mode  and order : `?command=pl_sort&id=<id>&val=<val>`
  If id=0 then items will be sorted in normal order, if id=1 they will be
  sorted in reverse order
  A non exhaustive list of sort modes:
    0 Id
    1 Name
    3 Author
    5 Random
    7 Track number

toggle random playback: `?command=pl_random`

toggle loop: `?command=pl_loop`

toggle repeat: `?command=pl_repeat`

toggle enable service discovery module : `?command=pl_sd&val=<val>`
Typical values are: sap; shoutcast; podcast; hal;

toggle fullscreen: `?command=fullscreen`

set volume level to  (can be absolute integer, percent or +/- relative value): `?command=volume&val=<val>`
Allowed values are of the form: +, -,  or %

seek to : `?command=seek&val=<val>`
Allowed values are of the form:
    [+ or -][:][:][]
    or [+ or -]%
    (value between [ ] are optional, value between < > are mandatory)
  examples:
    1000 -> seek to the 1000th second
    +1H:2M -> seek 1 hour and 2 minutes forward
    -10% -> seek 10% back

## playlist.xml: get the full playlist tree

## browse.xml: get dir's filelist

```
?dir=<dir>
```

## vlm.xml: get the full list of VLM elements

## vlm_cmd.xml: execute VLM command

```
?command=<cmd>
```

get the error message from

Answer (score 0):

As @JayanthKoushik said, you can accomplish this very easily using `pygame`

Here is a sample code of what you want:

```
import pygame
from time import sleep

pygame.init()

pygame.mixer.music.load('g:\\test.flv')
pygame.mixer.music.play()

while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():    #keep repeating while track is playing
    sleep(180)                          #Waits for 180 seconds or 3 minutes before pausing
    pygame.mixer.music.pause()
    sleep(120)                          #Waits for 120 seconds or 2 minutes before continuing
    pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
```